# How can I stop double-click on top of a word inside a table from selecting it?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I used the CSS:

```
table.grid {
    cursor: default;
}
```

So the cursor now stays as a pointer when I hover over words.

But when I double click on something in the table it is selected. How can I make it so that a double mouse click does not select inside of that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) property for that

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EeL2Y/)

```
table {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

---

Still, if you refer MDN, it will show a big red box which says that the property is *Non-Standard* so it's better to have JavaScript fallback by using `onmousedown` and `onselectstart` event with `return false`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onmousedown='return false;' onselectstart='return false;'>Prevent from selecting this</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/EeL2Y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...and make change as you need.Is this you need?

```
 <span class="test2">
          <a href="http://google.com">Double click me</a>
          <em tabindex="-1">&nbsp;</em>
        </span>
```

and css is

```
.test2 { 
        padding: 10px 0; 
        position: relative; 
    }
    .test2 em { 
        position: absolute; 
        top: -6px; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        bottom: -1px;
        z-index: 100; 
    }
    .test2 em:focus { 
        display: none; 
    }
```